# Why would you want to write to a file when writing VHDL?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, vhdl, verilog

I have never so far been in the need to write to a file when making a testbench in vhdl. Seeing the signals being plotted has always been enough so far.

Could someone please give me a case or the reason why you would write to a file?

Comment: The "file" can also be StdOut. Writing reports and messages like "ALL TEST PASSED" are not pulluted by simulator outputs. Or if you need special formats for other tools as an input e.g. to compare two simulation models or ....

Comment: Why are people voting to close this? It's a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @MattYoung Not really, this is the kind of questions which attract endless life stories. Any scenario involving file IO would be a valid answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are tons of reasons to do this.  Waveforms are often not enough, especially if say you are doing some behaviour modelling, or you need to see the impact of your implementation,or there is just too much data ...

One example might be you're designing a video processing circuit that needs to implement a specific output and you need to make sure your integer implementation doesn't introduce any meaningful error vs. a floating point implementation.  First off, this may not even be accessible within a normal persons lifetime as you scroll through the waveforms, you need to see the image of this processing pipeline.

This also allows you to implement your own scripts within your favourite scripting language with al sorts of nice add on features as opposed to using the skill, or TCL scripts that don't support some nice math package.

And this just scratches the surface ...

Answer (score 2):

I had to do it in a test bench of a small processor. Basically, I was providing a file containing the instructions, the verilog/vhdl was reading the file and executing the instructions. Then there was a special processor instruction, used at strategic locations, that dumped the current registers values in an output file.

When the execution was over, I was simply comparing the output file with a template to check that the execution exactly went as expected. This way, I could automate non-regression tests.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else, you want to write out "PASSED" or "FAILED" to STDOUT or a file, which means that you need add some amount of checking to your testbench, not just stimulus. This way every time you make a change to your design, you'll have a quick way of knowing how the change impacted the specified functionality. As your design becomes more complex, you'll appreciate not having to manually re-inspect everything over and over again.